# Вызов функции из actionscript 3 c помощь javascript

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

Подскажите как вызвать данную функцию в Javascript?

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

ExternalInterface.addCallback("play", pt);

function pt()
{
    var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
    mySound.load(new URLRequest("myFavSong.mp3"));
    mySound.play();
}
```